# is there a way to dynamically subscribe to events in websocket server in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to see if there is a way to dynamically use @SubscribeMessage() decorator.

So far, I have been able to listen to "known events" like in **Method(a)**. But I would like to dynamically generate the event-name <**Method (b)**> in controller and start listening to it in gateway.

or, I want to listen to all events emitted on that socket and process them as in **Method 2**

**Method(a):**

```
 @SubscribeMessage('event1')
  handleMessage(args[]){
  // DO STUFF
  }
```

**Method (b):**

```
  @SubscribeMessage(MY_DYNAMIC_EVENT_AT_RUNTIME)
  async handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string){
    //DO STUFF
 }
```

**Method 2:**

```
@SubscribeMessage(*)
  async handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string){
    //DO STUFF
  }
```

I saw some wildcard concepts for socket.io , How can I use it here with NestJs?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using rooms and namespaces

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).